# Json.NET CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver not working with private property setters

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Json.NET (8.0.3) and I am trying to use the CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver with JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject() so that I can read JSON with camel case properties. Here is an example of the JSON.

```
{ "name":"somename", "type":"sometype" }
```

Here is the class I am trying to deserialize to:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
}
```

If I use JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject the Name and Type values are null because technically the class property names do not match the JSON property names. This was expected. If I add the JsonProperty attribute then it will deserialize correctly (also expected).

```
public class MyClass {
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; private set; }
}
```

I do not want to put the JsonProperty attribute on all of the properties so I tried the CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerialierSettings {
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver()
};

MyClass value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

The Name and Type properties of the MyClass object are both null which was unexpected. If I make the setter public then it works correctly.

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The obvious answer here is to just keep the setter public, but if I want/need to have the setter private, how can I get the CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver to work with private setters? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by writing a custom `ContractResolver`

```
string json = @"{""name"":""somename"", ""type"":""sometype"" }";

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                         ContractResolver = new AllPropertiesContractResolver() };
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json,settings);

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
}
```

---

```
public class AllPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty()
                    {
                        PropertyName = x.Name,
                        PropertyType = x.PropertyType,
                        Readable = true,
                        ValueProvider = new AllPropertiesValueProvider(x),
                        Writable = true
                    })
                    .ToList();


        return props;
    }
}

public class AllPropertiesValueProvider : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IValueProvider
{
    PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;

    public AllPropertiesValueProvider(PropertyInfo p)
    {
        _propertyInfo = p;
    }

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        return _propertyInfo.GetValue(target);  //Serialization
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        _propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value, null); //Deserialization
    }
}
```

---

BTW: `If I use JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject the Name and Type values are null because technically the class property names do not match the JSON property names.` is not correct. If your properties had public setters and getters, deserialization would ignore the  cases when using default settings (this is what I use in this answer. My  ContractResolver additionally includes private properties in deserialization process; that is all).....

See the other question I used the same ContractResolver: [What am I doing wrong with JSON.NET's JsonConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408110/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-json-nets-jsonconvert)

Comment: @LB Thanks for the fast reply and the clarification about how deseralization works with private setters. So my options are to use the JsonProperty on each property with a private setter or to use a custom ContractResolver like the one you posted because it includes private setters?