# I want to convert a c# list into a JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

IF I USED JARRAY.FROMOBJECT i get an empty skeleton json, can someone help me letting me know how to convert the list into a jarray. Thanks

```
class EGTenantCreated
{
internal string id { get; set; }
internal string subject { get; set; }
internal EGData data { get; set; }
internal string eventType { get; set; }
internal string eventTime { get; set; }
internal string dataVersion { get; set; }
internal string metadataVersion { get; set; }
internal string topic { get; set; }
}

class EGData
{
internal string TenantId { get; set; }
internal string TenantName { get; set; }
internal string AdministratorEmail { get; set; }
internal string ProductId { get; set; }
internal string PackageInstanceId { get; set; }
internal string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public List<EGTenantCreated> UpdateEGTenant()
{
DateTime date = new DateTime();
string tenantName = "Tenant" + date.Day.ToString() + date.Month.ToString() + 
date.Year.ToString() + "_"
+ date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString();

string adminEmail = "user" + date.Day.ToString() + date.Month.ToString() + 
date.Year.ToString() + "_"
+ date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + "@testmail.com";

EGData egData = new EGData();
egData.TenantId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
egData.TenantName = tenantName;
egData.AdministratorEmail = adminEmail;
egData.ProductId = "Erp";
egData.PackageInstanceId = "522b0dc0-5db9-437d-97cc-cd4c742b1b22";
egData.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

EGTenantCreated egTenant = new EGTenantCreated();
egTenant.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
egTenant.subject = "/DeploymentRegistry/TenantCreated";
egTenant.eventType = "TenantCreated";
egTenant.eventTime = "2019-10-04T20:02:54.9411815Z";
egTenant.dataVersion = "1.0.0";
egTenant.metadataVersion = "1";
egTenant.topic = "topictest";
egTenant.data = egData;

List<EGTenantCreated> list = new List<EGTenantCreated>();
list.Add(egTenant);

return list;
}
var list = UpdateEGTenant();
var jArray = JArray.FromObject(list);  //here i get an empty json
```

Here is where i get the error, when i print the jArray.ToString() I get an empty json skeleton and am not getting my list converted into a jarray object thats what am expecting. This is real code.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://rextester.com/WCEE26110).

Comment: Based on the docs it looks like you could use [this constructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_3.htm): `var jDog = new JArray(doglist);`

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been upvoted. OP has stated an issue that doesn't seem to exist, and hasn't provided a reproduction case.

Comment: Get this error System.ArgumentException: 'Could not determine JSON object type for type Dog

Comment: When i do it I get an empty json skeleton it prints this: [
  {}
]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58703036/edit) to provide a [mcve] (the smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate the problem fully). Without this it's impossible to tell you why your code isn't working.

Comment: I already edited with real code, hope i can get help from you guys

Comment: Isn't it because all of your properties are `internal`?

Comment: Yeap @john, I move them to public, and now it works. How do you know it need to be moved to public?

Comment: @Josue Because I tested it. Also, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408110/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-json-nets-jsonconvert) which suggests another way of making it work.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Why are some members missing when trying to print an object by serializing to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48156976/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because your properties are `internal`. To work around this, you could make them `public` and the class `internal` (which is the default if no modifier is specified), or you could place the `JsonProperty` attribute on each property:

```
class EGTenantCreated
{
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal EGData data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string eventType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string eventTime { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string dataVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string metadataVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string topic { get; set; }
}

class EGData
{
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string TenantId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string TenantName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string AdministratorEmail { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string PackageInstanceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XLP45958)